# jQuery validator plugin time and date

Tags: jquery, mobile, methods, time, validation

i am using the jQuery validator plugin, which has no way to validate the date and time. By using the jQuery input features, i know that the time will be in the correct format.

```
<input type="time" id="time />
<input type="time" id="time2 />
<input type="date" id="date" />
```

However, can someone please teach me how to create a method that ensures that "time2" is no later than 11:59 PM or 23:59 and another method that requires "time2" to be greater than "time"

I have tried but I do not understand the syntax required for the addMethod function

Comment: which jQuery validator plugin your are using ?

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/g5CAY/1/)

[timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

```
$('#time2').attr('disabled', true);
$("#time").timepicker({
    timeOnly: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
}).change(function () {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val !== '') {
        var min = val.split(':');
        var min1 = min[1].split(' ');
        var minMin = parseInt(min1[0]);
        var minHour = ((min1[1] == 'am') ? parseInt(min[0]) : parseInt(min[0]) + 12);
        $('#time2').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('hasDatepicker').timepicker({
            timeOnly: true,
            timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',
            hourMin: minHour,
        }).change(function () {
            var val_to = this.value;
            var min_to = val_to.split(':');
            var min1_to = min_to[1].split(' ');
            var minMin_to = parseInt(min1_to[0]);
            var minHour_to = ((min1_to[1] == 'am') ? parseInt(min_to[0]) : parseInt(min_to[0]) + 12);
            if(minHour_to == minHour && minMin_to <= minMin){
                this.value = val;
            }
        });
    } else {
        $('#time2').attr('disabled', true);
    }
});
```